# Using Office 365 API in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, api, xamarin, office365

I am creating a sample for a talk: using Office 365 in Xamarin.Android, but I am having some errors, don´t know why :/

I got this:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. --->        
    Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceTransportException: Error: NameResolutionFailure ---> 
    System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure\n  
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  
    at Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000]
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper (Microsoft.OData.Client.ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  
    at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[QueryResult] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000]
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[Contact] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n 
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.IPagedEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact]].GetResult () [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper+<ExecuteAsync>d__2d`2[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Contact,Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact].MoveNext () [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.IPagedEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact]].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Office365InXamarinApps.ViewModel.ContactsViewModel+<GetContacts>d__3.MoveNext () [0x000b5] in d:\\DevApps\\GitHub\\Office365InXamarinApps\\scr\\Office365InXamarinApps\\Office365InXamarinApps\\ViewModel\\ContactsViewModel.cs:44 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact]].GetResult () [0x00000]
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Office365InXamarinApps.ViewModel.ContactsViewModel+<LoadData>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00030] 
    in d:\\DevApps\\GitHub\\Office365InXamarinApps\\scr\\Office365InXamarinApps\\Office365InXamarinApps\\ViewModel\\ContactsViewModel.cs:25 "   string
```

and this

```
"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. 
    ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {\"error\":{\"code\":\"ErrorInternalServerError\",\"message\":\"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\",\"innererror\":{\"message\":\"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\",\"type\":\"System.NullReferenceException\",\"stacktrace\":\"  
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.ContactSchema.<.cctor>b__2c(Entity e, PropertyDefinition ep, ServiceObject s, PropertyInformation sp)\\r\\n   
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.SimpleEwsPropertyProvider.GetProperty(Entity entity, PropertyDefinition property, ServiceObject ewsObject)\\r\\n   
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.ContactProvider.ItemTypeToEntity(ItemType itemType, IList`1 properties)\\r\\n   
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.ContactProvider.Find(String parentFolderId, ContactQueryAdapter queryAdapter)\\r\\n   
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.FindContactsCommand.InternalExecute()\\r\\n   
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataCommand`2.Execute()\\r\\n  
    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.ODataTask.Execute(TimeSpan queueAndDelayTime, TimeSpan totalTime)\"}}}\n  
    at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[QueryResult] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[Contact] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  
    at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[Contact] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[Contact] (System.Object source, Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext context, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000]
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.IPagedEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact]].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  
    at Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper+<ExecuteAsync>d__2d`2[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Contact,Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  
    at Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper+<ExecuteAsync>d__2d`2[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Contact,Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact].MoveNext () [0x00000] 
    in <filename unknown>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Extensions.IPagedEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.IContact]].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  
    at Office365InXamarinApps.ViewModel.ContactsViewModel+<GetContacts>d__4.MoveNext () [0x000d7] in d:\\DevApps\\GitHub\\Office365InXamarinApps\\scr\\Office365InXamarinApps\\Office365InXamarinApps\\ViewModel\\ContactsViewModel.cs:53 " string
```

The code is here:
https://github.com/saramgsilva/Office365InXamarinApp

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried to fix it? When did you get those stacktraces?

Comment: I get the error on Monday, on Tuesday and today ( LOL ), and like I said I doing a demo for one talk - "Using Office 365 API in Xamarin apps", and this errors happen in Xamarin.Android when I try to get the contacts from my account. And this a BUG! Would like to report it to the team but did not find a way :/

Comment: you can see this movie with the error (https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb7vnnbewwdcoxg/debug_untilError.mp4) I did the auth in test i did before, for this reason it don´t ask again...

Comment: I found an issue in IOS version, I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541318/nullreferenceexception-when-use-office-365-api-in-xamarin-ios :(((((

Comment: Guys from O365 team pointed me to the updated tooling: http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/05/office-365-api-tool-visual-studio-2013-summer-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office 365 API Preview has issues and I cannot use it, for this reason I created another demo using Office 365 REST API.

https://github.com/saramgsilva/Office365RESTAPISample